# usr/sbin/grub-probe error:failed to get canonical path of '/cow after ubuntu 16.04 update

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04

After I update the ubuntu version from 14.04 to 16.04 system not booting. screen sowing

```
grub>
```

Then I tried to update the grub as follows,
1/ boot the system using USB boot.
2. open the terminal and type

```
sudo update-grub
```

it throws the below error message.

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe:error:failed to get canonical path of '/cow'.
```

Googled and tried many forum answers. But could not solved.

Greatly appreciated your help.

Comment: I gone thru & tried the steps in the link before posting the question...